# How to draw a circle split in 10 slices?

Tags: vector-graphics

I'd like to draw and print a circle that's split in 10 slices (like a clock, but with 10 hours instead of 12 - 10 slices of 36 degrees each).

Can you recommend how to do this easily using (windows) software (preferably something that's not very esoteric)?

Comment: You could do it in excel with Pie Chart but I'm not really sure what is that you are after.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Inkscape, but it was a bit overwhelming.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Using Excel 2010**

Enter in equal values in Column A.  The number of rows entered will determine how many partitions your circle will have.

[image: 1]

From the Insert tab, create a 2D pie chart with the cells selected (A1 through A10):

[image: 2]

You will now have a circle cut into 10 slices, where you can then modify the color arrangements to meet your needs:

[image]

Comment: This didn't help broaden my horizons in handling vector image software :-P ... but did the job in an instant!

Answer (score 1):

Copy and Paste the data to an Excel Worksheet or write the data manually. Select all the data as shown. Select Insert->2-D Pie and the Pie will be shown. Choose the style that you like from Chart Design->Chart Style menu by selecting previously inserted 2-D Pie. Chart statistics data used to demonstrate this example is taken from:  https://www.usnews.com/news/best-countries/articles/2019-12-20/the-worlds-most-generous-countries

You can also customize the degrees for each pie to your wish.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So you can have 10, 36 degrees pie slices also. Here's the picture:

[image: 10, 36 degrees pie slices]

Comment: +1 for the effort. I have _no idea_ what I was trying to do 6 years ago with this circle :)